# Is the following "private static inner class" implementation correct?

Tags: java, static-methods, inner-classes, static-class, private-class

I have made a public "Utils" class, where I put some general **static** methods that are frequently used.
Inside that Utils class, I have created a private static inner class, of some "tool" that Utils supplies. (That tools is some kind of a parser for my needs).
One of the methods in Utils, returns a new instance of that parser, and everything works ok.
The "problem" is that I am getting warnings, for every **public** method inside the parser, that is not called from the containing Utils class.

This is the skeleton of how it looks:

```
public class Utils 
{
    public static Parser(String[] msgs) throws Exception
    {
        return Parser.create(msgs);
    }

    private static class Parser
    {       
        /** fields... **/

        private Parser()
        {}

        public static Parser create(String[] msgs) throws Exception
        {
            Parser parser = new Parser();
            setupParser(msgs);
            return parser;
        }

        private static void setupParser(String[] msgs) throws Exception
            { // do stuff 
            }

        public boolean someInnerMethod(String key)
            {
            // do stuff
            }
     }
}
```

The method `someInnerMethod` raises the warning:

> The method someInnerMethod(String) from the type Utils.Parser is never used locally

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way of doing what I have done here?
I generally want the Parser not to be accessible from the outside, yet getting it could be possible using a static method (I don't want to instantiate a Utils class every time I need it's methods)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your one "do stuff" comment is commenting out a closing `}`. But that might just be because of you removing irrelevant code

Comment: Do you really need an inner class? Is `Parser` used only inside `Utils`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not correct. You won't be able to use your class - You cannot use the return value in your static factory method (right now it won't compile, but I guess the return value is supposed to be `Parser`). The visibility of the return value makes it inaccessible for anyone using your factory method.

A workaround would be to factor out a public interface that the inner class implements and use this as the return value for your factory method.

Comment: The class can also just be made public. Its constructor is private.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did try that workaround - but then I "lose" access to all of the "public" methods inside `Parser`. Casting the object from the Interface to `Parser` is also not an option since it's not visible.
What I generally want to do is allow that `Parser` object to be created only in Utils, but to be retrieved from outer classes, using some static method in Utils, and then, of course, be able to approach it's public methods.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie what sebastian meant is that by including your public methods in the interface that is returned the caller has access to those methods that are included in the interface definition.

Answer (score 2):

While the methods are public, the class itself is private, so those methods are *effectively* private as they're only accessible from within the containing class.  Your IDE appears to be treating them the same as `private` methods, warning you if you define one that is never called.

P.S. as an aside, there's no such thing as a "static inner class" - the term "inner class" refers to a non-static nested class whose instances can only exist in the context of a particular instance of the container, so a class cannot be both *static* and *inner* at the same time.